# How to know if vim call from Git, in vimrc

Tags: git, vim

### .gitconfig

```
    [core]
    editor = /usr/bin/vim
```

### .vimrc

`autocmd VimEnter * NERDTree ./`

### I don't want to call this in git commit.

I want to this

```
    if !gitcommit
      autocmd VimEnter * NERDTree ./
    endif
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This snippet should put you in the right direction:

```
augroup IsNotGitCommit
  autocmd!
  autocmd VimEnter * NERDTree ./
augroup END

autocmd BufRead COMMIT_EDITMSG autocmd! IsNotGitCommit
```

The `NotGitCommit` group contains your generic `autocmd` that works with any "regular" file.

The other `autocmd` is triggered when you edit a commit message, before the `VimEnter` event, and removes the `NotGitCommit` group.

Answer (score 3):

One option would be to include the `-u <path>` option in your `vim` command, which specifies an alternate `.vimrc` file to load. Then you could have a `.vimrc` specifically for `git commit`.

Alternatively, you can use the `--cmd <command>` option for your `vim` command, which will execute a vim command **before** loading your regular `.vimrc` - so you could have that command set a variable which your `.vimrc` will check before running your autocmd.

Comment: I now keep a separate "bare" vimrc, which I use for git. This not only fixes some errors that I get in git commit, it also speeds up the boot time of vim.